# What current moderator elections are happening?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Is there a list of the current elections that are going to be held i.e. in the next week?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>Any ongoing/active elections will show up at the top of the homepage on the [elections tracker information page thingy](http://elections.stackexchange.com/).</s> The elections tracker was taken offline during the big transition to HTTPS and is no longer available. There are not currently any plans to host it ourselves, although it is something that we've discussed before.

We do not currently publicize a list of upcoming elections, as the list could change at any moment based on the needs of the individual sites. Moderators are provided a list of sites with elections currently ongoing and starting this week, and sometimes an election scheduled for the week after, but it is not a comprehensive list of everything because dates can change on a whim.

Comment: Down at the bottom of that screen, next to "Programmers", the icon is broken. I guess that's something to do with it now being "Software Engineering"?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Probably. The elections page is an [open source project](https://github.com/tms/stack-election) maintained by Tim Stone, but I think he didn't have much time for it recently.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Updated. Unfortunately it's just plain gone, so it probably doesn't help you any more. :P

Answer (score 9):

Since all elections are accompanied by [election](/questions/tagged/election) posts on the Meta sites of the communities, we can [query the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1569937/questions-with-a-specific-tag-on-all-per-site-metas?TagName=election%3E%25%27+OR+p.Tags+LIKE+%27%25%3Celections) for ongoing and future elections. This is the current result:

[image]

The announcement posts ([example](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15248/116151)) have a standard template but it doesn't mention the election date; it *could* be determined from the posting date but sometimes elections are extended (or cancelled/automatically completed due to a lack of candidates). That is what [this query does](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1569971/election-dates):

[image]

Please note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning. Elections end on Tuesday evenings.

Comment: Arts & Crafts was missing because it made use of the tag `elections` instead of `election`. I'm not sure how the script works, or if it actually filters posts by tags, but maybe it's more convenient to include that tag as well (I just edited all Meta posts on A&C, though :).

Comment: No need for SEDE with its one week delay (which can be crucial in elections), can achieve pretty much the same using [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters/423143/elections?sort=active) on se.com portal. :)

Comment: Thanks, some SQL injection to the rescue - see the updated query.

Comment: Can you find nominations or their parent in SEDE? I thought they might be a special type of post. (Apparently, moderators can edit that parent?)

Comment: @Laurel [yes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1569950)

Comment: Just to note, this will miss the sites that have non-English tags. e.g. [スタック・オーバーフロー's election](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/1) since the [meta announcement](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3708/51885) uses the tag "選挙" instead of "election"